# Contributions Lost in Time

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

What happens to good Physics questions and answers lost by people who lost their accounts either which a way?

Comment: What do you mean by "lose their accounts"? Losing access? Or having the account removed?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty yes to all

Comment: The closure or deletion of accounts does not imply closure or deletion of posts, and vice-versa. They are independent decisions.

Answer (score 6):

If someone loses access to their account, the posts remain, but the user will be unable to edit them (as the OP) until they regain access.

Accounts are usually deleted (1) because of administrative reasons such as sockpuppetting or voting fraud, in which case there are likely no salvageable posts, or (2) because the user has requested it. In this case the posts also remain, stripped of a link to the poster's profile and with the poster username sometimes changed to the form userXXXX.

That's it, really.

And, as before, seriously: all this information is available with minimal digging at the [Help Center](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/help) and in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). If you're asking for a specific reason we can help, but if you're just randomly wondering about stuff, please have a thorough look in those places first.

Comment: [Example](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45110/8563) of a post living on past the departure of its owner from the site.